# Hide Toolbar for list webpart on modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-pages

I have added a list view webpart on modern view. How can I hide toolbar from view?

[image]

Also, I want to add text webpart with hyperlinks via powershell. Please suggest how can I do that? I can add simple text but no idea on hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no supported way to hide the toolbar in the out-of-the-box views for lists. However, if you're using the List web part there is a property you can use to hide the command bar (toolbar).

[image: Properties pane]

Answer (score 3):

Recently MS introduced the "Hide Command bar switch" as a  part of the list webpart properties. Turning that off, should hide the "New and Quick Edit" controls

-Ravi